# How to look up data of 2 specific dates with pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I´m pretty new to MongoDB and have of course googled this problem but most of the results only refer to getting the data between 2 dates.
The Timestamp column in my db looks like this:

```
TIMESTAMP :2022-08-21T08:02:21.000+00:00
```

I want get all documents that match a specific date. I know that the timedelta is a weird way of doing this but I wanted to play around a bit. Anyway my problem is that the code below gives me exactly 1 document even though there should be houndreds. Another problem is that I haven´t found a solution to bypass the need for a start and end time for both dates so that I can just use

```
"$and":[ {"TIMESTAMP": {'$eq': today, '$eq': past}]
```

Code:

```
def delta(timeframe):
        from datetime import datetime, timedelta
        #subtract time
        search_column = "TIMESTAMP"
    
        if timeframe == "1":
            today = datetime.today()    
            past = today - timedelta(days=1)
            #format dates
            today_end = datetime.strftime(today, '%Y-%m-%d' + " 23:59:59")
            today_start = datetime.strftime(today, '%Y-%m-%d' + " 00:00:00")
            past_start = datetime.strftime(past, '%Y-%m-%d' + " 00:00:00")
            past_end = datetime.strftime(past, '%Y-%m-%d' + " 23:59:59")
            print(past_end,past_start)
            #convert strings to datetime
            past_start = datetime.strptime(past_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            today_start = datetime.strptime(today_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            past_end = datetime.strptime(past_end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            today_end = datetime.strptime(today_end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
          
            a = collection.find({"$and":[ {"TIMESTAMP": {'$lt': today_end, '$gte': today_start},"TIMESTAMP": {'$lt': past_end, '$gte': past_start}}]})
            list_cur = list(a) #convert the cursor to the list of dictionary.
            df = pd.DataFrame(list_cur)
            #b= json.loads(dumps(a))
            print(df)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Looking at your text and your code, it's confusing to know what you want to find.  You seem to ask for a `"TIMESTAMP"` that is today _and also_ yesterday, which is of course impossible.  Are you looking for any documents in the collection where `"TIMESTAMP"` is today?

Comment: `collection.find({"$and" ...` -  in this query you are looking for an OR operation (use `$or` logical operator).

Comment: I´ve tried ´$or´ already with the same result which is why I switched to the ´$and´ operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly brackets are misplaced.
`$and` and `$or` operator, contains a list of conditions. So each of your condition should be a new element in the array.

```
{"$or":[ 
    {"TIMESTAMP": {'$lt': today_end, '$gte': today_start}},
    {"TIMESTAMP": {'$lt': past_end, '$gte': past_start}}
]}
```

This can be translated to :

> I want all the documents where (TIMESTAMP is between today_end and
> today_start) or (TIMESTAMP is between past_end and past_start)

PS: I think you need to use `$or`